# Why are these results so different when using Python's "float" function?

Tags: python, math, floating-point, type-conversion, converters

My Python code was doing something strange to me (or my numbers, rather):

a)

```
float(poverb.tangibles[1])*1000
1038277000.0
```

b)

```
float(poverb.tangibles[1]*1000)
inf
```

Which led to discovering that:

```
long(poverb.tangibles[1]*1000)
```

produces the largest number I've ever seen.

Uhhh, I didn't read the whole Python tutorial or it's doc. Did I miss something critical about how `float` works?

EDIT:

```
>>> poverb.tangibles[1]
u'1038277'
```

Comment: This question would be far easier to answer if you give us the value of `poverb.tangibles[1]`

Comment: +1 for constructive feedback. best. site. ever.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you probably missed is docs on how multiplication works on strings.  Your `tangibles` list contains *strings*.  `tangibles[1]` is a string.  `tangibles[1]*1000` is that string repeated 1000 times.  Calling `float` or `long` on that string interprets it as a number, creating a huge number.  If you instead do `float(tangibles[1])`, you only get the actual number, not the number repeated 1000 times.

What you are seeing is just the same as what goes on in this example:

```
>>> x = '1'
>>> x
'1'
>>> x*10
'1111111111'
>>> float(x)
1.0
>>> float(x*10)
1111111111.0
```

Comment: Yah, string "multiplication" does tend to surprise but since it is actually sequence multiplication (where strings are a kind of sequence) it's part of the language and ain't going away. Along those lines, `string % integer` also isn't what you might guess.